# Multiple (same) Many-To-One relations in same model

Tags: django

I got a model `Device`. Each Device has 3 sensors which have there own color, status etc..

So I created a class `Sensor` where I need to store all the sensor data.

Now I want in my `Device` model an attribute for each sensor that is connected with the Sensor model so I can retrieve the data.

What's the best way to do this?

Doing it like this?:

in Device model for each sensor:

```
light_sensor = models.ForeignKey(
        Sensor, on_delete=SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
    )
```

or in Sensor model:

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="devicesensor"
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
```

Comment: Each device has *exactly* three sensors, or *at most*, *at leat*? Is it likely that this will change in the future?

Comment: exactly and in the future there can be added

Answer (score 1):

What you want in a many-to-one relationship where *many* sensors connect to *one* device. **In this case the foreign key goes on the many side.** Therefore each sensor should have a foreign key pointing back to its device.

- [Django Docs: Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Here's a rough example.

```py
from django.db import models

class Device(models.Model):
    pass

class Sensor(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="devicesensor"
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
```

Now from the shell let's create a device with some sensors using `manage.py shell`...

```py
# create device
d = Device()
d.save()

# create sensors
s1 = Sensor(device=d, status='online', color='green');
s1.save()
s2 = Sensor(device=d, status='online', color='green');
s2.save()
s3 = Sensor(device=d, status='online', color='green');
s3.save()

# get sensors
d = Device.objects.first()
d.devicesensor.all()
```

Comment: I know what you mean. But then I need a device & sensor attribute in my Sensor class? While in my Device class I only need to set the color & status of the sensor

Comment: @codinginquarantine I'm a little confused. To clarify, you would like each each `Sensor` to have a color and a status property and you want to be able to set the values of these properties from the `Device`?

Comment: yes. I tried the implementation you proposed. But if I need to set the values of the sensor I need to do this by filtering on the Sensor class. I would like to do this via the Device class, is that possible? And better question: is that better? It just needs to be the most efficient way. 

The sensor color and status are set each 10 minutes and retrieved a lot. So it may not take to much time to execute a write and read for it

Comment: I want to be able to set the values of the sensor via Device class and then just need to do device.save() so they are stored

Comment: It would be great if I can set the values of the sensor without need to query the sensor table. I already have the device attribute on the point where I want to set the color/status.

Comment: You can get all of the sensors straight from the device, then update the values and save. I've updated my answer above. Cheers.

Comment: ok but on some point in code we don't know if there already is a sensor available for the device. So an update or create query is needed there then?

Comment: Yes, you could just check the length of `d.devicesensor.all()` to determine how many devices, or you could see if `d.devicesensor.first()` is null to tell if there are any sensors available.

Comment: I don't know if that will work. As we have 3 different records.. I will try it! thanks